# Armadillo element wise multiplication speed

Tags: c++, armadillo

Is element wise multiplication (%) speed in armadillo depends whether LAPACK/BLAS is installed? Im currently running armadillo without them installed and speed is awful.
Ok here is the simplest code, which takes eternity to calculate

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "conio.h"


    #include "armadillo"

    using namespace arma;
    using namespace std;

    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {


    int n=250; 
    mat X=ones(n,n);

    mat quan;



  for (int xi=1;xi<=256;xi++)
  {  
          quan = exp(X)%exp(X);
  }



  getch();


  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Armadillo does use external implementations of LAPACK and BLAS, so they certainly could affect it's speed.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?  Otherwise we might be just guessing what the underlying cause is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have optimisation flags enabled in your compiler settings (eg. in GCC or Clang, use -O2 or -O3).  Armadillo makes use of [template metaprogramming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming), and like any C++ template library, this absolutely requires optimisation enabled within the compiler to be effective.  For example, this also applies to C++ template libraries such as Boost.

Comment: I've installed blas and lapack and nothing seems to change. Speed is nowhere near to matlab

Comment: The double-precision exp() function will always be slow, in any language.  Use an approximation to exp() (possibly enabled via compiler flags), or change the Armadillo matrix type from 'mat' to 'fmat'.  This will use the single-precision exp which is much faster.

Anyway, why don't you reformulate the loop from exp(x)*exp(y) to  exp(x+y), which is equivalent?

Comment: Matlab just wraps MKL, which makes uses of parallelization and all kind of optimization that is out there. If you don't link with MKL and use a good compiler (at least with the O3 option) you can never get even close

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calculating `exp(X)` twice? You're not benchmarking elementwise multiplication; you're apparently benchmarking `exp()`.  Also, why are you not using `expmat()` or `expmat_sym()`?